# MYSQL query slow on ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trouble with the speed of this mysql query. I think the problem is the order with t1.auto_increment. If I use t1.id1 as ORDER BY it is fast, but I need to order on the t1.auto_increment value.

```
SELECT id1 FROM t1 
WHERE id1 IN (SELECT id2 FROM t2 WHERE Essential_Column_Name = '1') 
GROUP BY t1.id1
ORDER BY t1.auto_increment DESC LIMIT 6
```

Can anyone help me making it faster?

Comment: Inner select might be responsible for slowness too.

Comment: Presumably `ID` is fast because you have a clustered index on it.  It would probably make more sense in this case to remove that index, change it to a regular one and put your clustered index on your `auto_increment` column

Comment: I was going to say what @paqogomez said - with the addition that if this table is write-intensive then that could also be causing slowness when ordering on an auto-incrementing column (regardless of whether it's indexed).

Comment: Questions about query performance cannot be answered without providing CREATE statements for the relevant tables and the query's EXPLAIN.

Comment: Thanks guys! Piotr gave me the thought to use a normal left join and its indeed faster than using the Inner Select. It queries in 0.0172 sec now :-)